# How do I reset iCloud for a particular user?

Tags: macos, icloud, mac-appstore, mac-mini

I can get into the App Store from two other users on the same computer - a Mac Mini.

However, when I attempt to go to App Store, or iCloud on USER1 I get the message "there is an error signing into the Apple server." When I then logon as either USER2 or USER3, there is no problem.

What can I do to fix/reset/restore/redo whatever so I can go to the App Store and also use iCloud with USER1.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact version of macOS you're using?

Comment: El Capitan 10.11.6. USER1, by the way, is the one that has access to the HardDrive, docs, etc., whereas the other two don't when I log in. They are pretty empty at this point. (One was a test so it's reallllly empty).